# How does ggplot compute confidence intervals for regressions?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, ggplot2

The R plotting package ggplot2 has an awesome function called [stat_smooth](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/stat_smooth.html) for plotting a regression line (or curve) with the associated confidence band.

However I am having a hard time figuring out exactly how this confidence band is generated, for every time of regression line (or "method"). How can I find this information?

Comment: See the section entitled "Details" in your link.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent : I have read that section, but I still have trouble connecting the dots. I use the "rlm" method for fitting a line, how is the confidence interval computed (mathematically, what equation/algorithm?) ? How can I find that information?

Comment: So I think you should ask a more precise question.

Comment: I think your question is reasonably precise... but I suspect you will not get an answer here.  You may have better luck at the ggplot2 google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ggplot2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the `Details` section of the help

> Calculation is performed by the (currently undocumented) predictdf
>   generic function and its methods. For most methods the confidence
>   bounds are computed using the predict method - the exceptions are
>   loess which uses a t-based approximation, and for glm where the normal
>   confidence interval is constructed on the link scale, and then
>   back-transformed to the response scale.

So [predictdf](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth-methods.r) will generally call `stats::predict`, which in turn will call the correct `predict` method for the smoothing method. Other functions involving [stat_smooth](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth.r)  are also useful to consider.

Most model fitting functions will have `predict` method associated with the `class` of the model. These will usually take a `newdata` object and an argument `se.fit` that will denote whether the standard errors will be fitted. (see `?predict`) for further details.

> `se`
>   display confidence interval around smooth? (TRUE by default, see level to control

This is passed directy to the predict method to return the appropriate standard errors (method dependant)

> `fullrange`
>   should the fit span the full range of the plot, or just the data

This defines the `newdata` values for `x` at which the predictions will be evaluated

> `level`
>   level of confidence interval to use (0.95 by default)

Passed directly to the predict method so that the confidence interval can define the appropriate critical value (eg `predict.lm` uses `qt((1 - level)/2, df)` for the standard errors to be multiplied by

> `n`
>   number of points to evaluate smoother at

Used in conjunction with `fullrange` to define the `x` values in the `newdata` object.

Within a call to `stat_smooth` you can define `se` which is what is partially matched to `se.fit` (or `se`), and will define the `interval` argument if necessary. `level` will give level of the confidence interval (defaults 0.95).

The `newdata` object is defined within the processing, depending on your setting of `fullrange` to a sequence of length `n` within the full range of the plot or the data.

In your case, using `rlm`, this will use `predict.rlm`, which is defined as

```
predict.rlm <- function (object, newdata = NULL, scale = NULL, ...)
{
    ## problems with using predict.lm are the scale and
    ## the QR decomp which has been done on down-weighted values.
    object$qr <- qr(sqrt(object$weights) * object$x)
        predict.lm(object, newdata = newdata, scale = object$s, ...)
}
```

So it is internally calling `predict.lm` with an appropriate scaling of the `qr` decomposition and `scale` argument.

Comment: ... and predict.rlm is hidden inside MASS ... and the call to predictdf passes model, xseq, se, and level arguments to predict.rlm... but where did those values come from?  Well, I guess that depends on what happens when arguments are passed from stat_smooth to StatSmooth$new ... which then in turn calls ...

Comment: My point being, that your answer is a step in the right direction, but answering OPs question entirely is not as trivial as it first seems (although one expects the code will behave sensibly... one isn't sure unless one traces it fully)

Comment: One does expect the code to behave sensibly, if the `predict` method has been set up in a standard way. I've edited my answer to to address the issues raised in your first comment.

Comment: @mnel: many thanks for this very detailed and useful answer!